# Copy DVD Movies Onto Blu Ray

Tags: dvd, blu-ray

I have a few (movie) DVDs that, thanks to repeated mishandling by the kids, don't play very well on the DVD player. But before they got too bad, I managed to make ISO image copies of them - if I recall correctly, I used dd to do this.

I can watch these ISO images just fine on the computer using vlc, but what I really want is to be able to watch them on the television. This requires burning them back onto discs.

I suppose the easy thing to do would be to buy a set of dual layer DVDs and use dd to write to them. But as I already have an external Blu Ray writer and some blank BD-R discs, perhaps it might be better to go down this route.

Ideally I would want to write these discs so that they just automatically play like any other movie when inserted into my (at the moment theoretical) Blu Ray player, instead of users messing around with navigating the file system. And even more ideally I suppose I should be able to fit two or three DVD movies onto one Blu Ray disc.

Does anyone know if this is all easily possible to do without a lot of messing about? I gather that the menu system is completely different on DVDs and Blu Rays, so that may be one problem. And I understand that the movies will not be in 1080p format, but that's fine.

If this isn't really possible and I just have to save the movies as files on a disc, then which file format would you recommend saving them in?

Answer (score 0):

creating a Blu-ray video disc from a DVD ISO image can be a bit more involved than simply copying the ISO image to a disc, but it is definitely possible with the right tools and software

you can create a Blu-ray video disc from a DVD ISO image but it will be way more time consumming than simply copying the ISO image to a disc, still you can do it with the right softwares like ImgBurn and Nero, here are the steps:

1. Convert your DVD ISO image to a Blu-ray compatible format: To do
   this, you'll need software that can convert your DVD ISO image to a
   format compatible with Blu-ray video discs. One popular tool for
   this is ImgBurn, which can convert your DVD ISO image to a Blu-ray
   compatible format and create a Blu-ray video disc image (.iso) file.
2. Author a Blu-ray video disc: To create a Blu-ray video disc that
   plays automatically on your player, you'll need to author it using a
   software tool that supports Blu-ray authoring, such as DVDStyler or
   Nero. This involves creating menus, chapters, and other features
   that are compatible with Blu-ray video discs. You'll also need to
   include any necessary video and audio files in the appropriate
   format.
3. Burn the Blu-ray video disc: Once you've authored your Blu-ray video
   disc, you can burn it to a blank BD-R disc using a tool like ImgBurn
   or Nero. Make sure to select the appropriate settings to ensure the
   disc is burned correctly and will play automatically on your player.

And for the format you have to use one that is compatible with Blu-ray video discs such as MPEG-2, H.264, or VC-1